# можно ли написать, что масштабы деятельности набирают обороты?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Масштабы моей профессиональной деятельности набирают обороты, и я, как человек, идущий в ногу со временем и тенденциями, решила активно продвигать свои соцсети

Comment: Что означает «свои»? Это — слова основателя (владельца) соцсетей?

Answer (score 2):

*Масштабы моей профессиональной деятельности набирают обороты, и я, как человек, идущий в ногу со временем и тенденциями, решила активно продвигать свои соцсети.*

Написать так можно, но **правильно ли это будет** – вот в чем вопрос.

У меня есть такие замечания:

1. **Набирать обороты** – это скорее ускоряться, а не увеличиваться.

[https://kartaslov.ru/какими-бывают/масштабы%20деятельности](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

2. Однородные отношения между **временем и тенденциями** выглядят не лучшим образом.  **ТЕНДЕ́НЦИЯ,**  ж. 1. Направление в движении или развитии чего-л. Это слово здесь выглядит лишним.
3. **Стиль фразы не выдержан**:  местоимение "я" плохо сочетается  с канцелярскими штампами вида «набирать обороты», «идти в ногу со временем».
4. Если уж идти в ногу со временем, то желательно придерживаться **информативного стиля**: меньше слов и больше информации.

Не стоит перегружать будущих читателей  пустыми и длинными фразами, если то же самое можно сказать просто и понятно. Это тоже можно считать стилистической погрешностью.

Вариант правки:

***Масштабы моей профессиональной деятельности увеличиваются, и я, в соответствии с требованиями времени, решила активно продвигать свои соцсети.***

Answer (score 0):

Я против конструкции "масштабы ... набирают обороты", если это серьезныый текст. Здесь, судя по всему, смешиваются два фразеологизма, едва ли не штампа. "Набирать обороты" - в значении "увеличиваться, нарастать" (в отношении какой-либо деятельности) и "масштабы [деятельности]"  - вместо объем, величина, размер. Каждоен из них вполне приемлемо само по себе, но вместе производи впечатление скорее ироническое, чем то (патетическое?), на которое, видимо, рассчитывал автор.

Самое простое - убрать слово "масштаб". Зачем оно тут? А заодно, кстати, и "деятельность".
Мое предприятие набирало обороты, мой проект, моя задумка - ну что у вас там.